# Bootstrap dropdown doesn't work in Angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have an *Angular* project that uses a *dropdown* from *bootsnipp* (*Bootstrap snippets*). The problem I'm having is that the dropdown won't work with the search bar.

//HTML

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span id="search_concept">Search In</span> <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-th" aria-hidden="true"></i> All Category</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-laptop" aria-hidden="true"></i> IT Solutions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush" aria-hidden="true"></i> Design and Multimedia</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> Social Media and Marketing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="search_param" value="all" id="search_param">         
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="x" placeholder="Enter search keyword here">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
  </span>
</div>
```

//JS

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  $('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
    var concept = $(this).text();
    $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
    $('.input-group #search_param').val(param);
  });
}
```

Comment: is there any javascript error in the console?

Comment: have you included bootstrap and jquery in angularcli.json file

Comment: How are you capturing the click event? Can you check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to avoid jQuery in Angular. Angular have on way to do these tasks. First you need to understand how dropdown works in bootstrap. When you click on dropdown button or link it just add a class on your dropdown to show menu and the class name is "show".
Now you know how it works. Now it's time to implement. Follow following steps to done your task.

1. Declare a toggleFlag named variable in your component.

   public toggleFlag = false;
2. Now create a click event on your dropdown menu button. This will call a method in your component.

   Search In
3. Now create show method in your component. This method will chnage toggleFlag variable.

   public showDropdown() {
     this.toggleFlag = !this.toggleFlag;
   }
4. Now it's time to use toggleFlag varibale in your template.

   ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" [ngClass]="{'show': toggleFlag}"

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this ngx-bootstrap .

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns